Find all x such that (x & (x+y)) == 0
Given an unsigned 64-bit integer y, is there an efficient way to find all unsigned 64-bit integers x such that
(x & (x + y)) == 0?
Some examples for small y:

y=0: only possible solution x=0
y=1: all solutions are of the form x=(1<<n)-1 for some n>=0
y=2: all solutions are of the form x=(1<<n)-2 for some n>=1
y=3: either x=(1<<n)-3, n>=2, or x=(1<<n)-2, n>=1

In general, the number of cases to consider depends on the number of runs of ones and zeros in the bit representation of y.
A solution to the problem could be an iterator function, that finds the next valid x, like the following:
uint64 next(uint64 x, uint64 y) {
    x++;
    while (x & (x+y)) x++;
    return x;
}

As the criterion (x & (x + y)) == 0 is rather simple, this might be a known problem for which a more efficient solution than the above is available.

Please take some time to refresh the [help], especially What topics can I ask about here? and What types of questions should I avoid asking? Also don't forget [ask] or how to write the "perfect" question, especially its checklist. In short, what have you tried? What is the underlying problem you need to solve?

Why is "Can someone help me?" not a useful question?

Note depending on the Hamming weight (number of '1' bits) in x this may be a large list. E.g. if x has 16 1-bits, then there are 2^48 values for y; if you can output each in 100ns-CPU (which is fairly optimistic) and fully parallelize over 100 cores (which is not very hard) it will take over a day -- and storing the output will take something like 100,000 20TB disks, currently about 30 million dollars

@dave_thompson_085: It is more than 2^48.

I just wrote a program that solves it for an increasing number of bits at a time which works fine for smallish y, but I can't store all the results in RAM for y much over 32 bits. time ./xandxplusy.bin 12345678901 Found 7665275 u64 x s.t. x & (x + 12345678901) = 0 real 0m0.600s time ./xandxplusy.bin 1234567890123
Found 104091717 u64 x s.t. x & (x + 1234567890123) = 0 real 0m6.599s

I could create an iterator instead if the 'next' results don;t have to be in numerical order. Otherwise, I think you have to get all the results upfront. The unordered iterator solution wouldn't need much RAM.

FWIW I wrote another program just to find the count of the number of u64 solutions. The most I've found so far is 27777890035288 u64 x s.t. x & (x + 6148914691236517205) = 0. So, at 8 bytes each, that's ~222TB. I can't be 100% sure at this stage this is the max though. I also found a way of returning the results in numerical order without a huge memory requirement.

For any given y, if x is a solution, then every suffix of x, including 0, is also a solution.
If you arrange the 64-bit integers into a tree such that each node's parent is a suffix formed by turning off the highest 1 bit, then the solutions will correspond to a subtree rooted at 0, and you can enumerate them by walking this tree.
Working from the root, then, if we have a solution x, then we need to find the new highest bits we could set that also produce valid solutions.  Those are conveniently exactly the 1 bits in x+y that are greater than x.  These can be efficiently enumerated, leading to an efficient recursive solution.
Here is an implementation in python.  You can turn it into an iterator if you like:
def printSolutions(y, prevx=0, mask=0):
    print(prevx)
    bits = (prevx+y) & ~mask & ((1<<64)-1)
    while bits > 0:
        bit = bits & -bits
        bits -= bit
        x = prevx | bit
        printSolutions(y, x, bit | (bit-1))

